# Optimize onDraw() in custom complicated view

Tags: android, animation, optimization, android-custom-view

I have icons which are represented as View's and all drawing are fully calculating in onDraw method with 'invalidation' on every frame (https://github.com/torryharris/Skycons). I have no ability to get these icons in gif format or other so I need to optimize their drawing because after like 30 second I get 'XXX skiped frame' message in logcat and frozen ui. I know that in OpenGL you could make calculating in background thread and then just swap drawing's buffers so animation will be smooth and nice. Can I do something similiar in Android or has Android some tricks for optimizing drawing views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use SurfaceView with background thread.